# Messing up data declared using tikzmath: is there a size limit?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmath

For chemistry, I need to rewrite many periodic tables showing different kinds of data for each chemical element.
I'm trying to declare all values using \tikzmath in order to access the values easily, as in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{math}


\begin{document}
%\input{../PTSI/annexes/data-chimie.tex}
\tikzmath{
\ZH=1;
\ZHe=2;
\ZLi=3;
\ZBe=4;
\ZB=5;
\ZC=6;
\ZN=7;
\ZO=8;
\ZF=9;
\ZNe=10;
\ZNa=11;
%% symboles
let \symbole1={H};
let \symbole2={He};
let \symbole3={Li};
let \symbole4={Be};
let \symbole5={B};
let \symbole6={C};
let \symbole7={N};
let \symbole8={O};
let \symbole9={F};
let \symbole10={Ne};
let \symbole11={Na};
let \symbole12={Mg};
%% masses molaire
\masse1=1.00794;
\masse2=4.002602;
\masse3=6.941;
\masse4=9.012182;
\masse5=10.811;
\masse6=12.0107;
\masse7=14.0067;
\masse8=15.9994;
\masse9=18.9984032;
\masse10=20.1797;
\masse11=22.98976928;
\masse12=24.305;
}
La masse molaire de \symbole1 est \SI{\masse1}{\gram\per\mol}.
La masse molaire de \symbole\ZLi est \SI{\masse\ZLi}{\gram\per\mol}.
Et pour \symbole2, on a bien Z=\ZHe, et une masse molaire de \SI{\masse2}{\gram\per\mol}
\end{document}
```

In fact, this MWE is working properly if the number of elements is less than ten. With only the 3 first:
[image: correct result]

But if I have more than 9 chemical elements, ( the `\tikzmath{...}` stuff in the input the `data-chimie.tex` file should contains data for up to 118 chemicals), the code execute properly but the data aren't the good ones... As I extracted the data for the MWE by copy/past from the files, I expect results should be the same!
[image: wrong result]

Is there a limit in the use of `tikzmath{}` to avoid such a mess? Can I change this limit if it exists? If it isn't such a problem, what could it be?

Comment: you should show an example of the failing code, hard to debug working code, one random guess though: how are you accessing the symbols after 9?

Comment: I think you got it, I edited my question with more than 10 chemicals, and the mess happens. To answer your question I'm accessing the symbols after 9 as the others, and I suspect, as you are, that it is the problem...

Comment: as I guessed you have `\symbole10` which is `\symbole{1} 0` you want `\symbole{10}`  you _should_ always brace arguments, if you have used `\symbole{1}` you would not have been tempted to use `\symbole10`. You would see the same with `\fbox10`  as opposed to `\fbox{10}` it's general tex syntax not specific to this command

Comment: Ok, it works adding the braces. In the pgfmanual (page 704), it's written: "The index does not have to be a number. By using braces {}, more sophisticated indices can be created", and I missunderstood it as "for any number, no need for braces", and just followed the examples... Thank you!